# SonarQube REST APIs : Read Metrics

Tags: sonarqube, devops

I am using SonarQube version 6.7.1

I am trying to get JSON Response for our projects sonarQube statistics
Just want simple details like

- Bug count, vulnerability count , % code duplication , code coverage
- Tried URL http://sonar-server:9000/api/metrics&json=true but got error Unknown url, can someone point out correct URL
- End Aim is to store Above counts for each run in time series DB .. any suggestions how to do it ?

May be i am not reading / understanding documentation clearly , possibly a pointer to tutorial or example or some other pointers will help me,

Comment: Have you consulted the "Web API" link in the SonarQube footer?

Comment: you mean this https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Web+API ?

Comment: tried this sonarqube.server.com:9000/web_api/api/metrics/domains/search&json=true ... didnt work , not getting JSON response

Comment: Gentle Reminder , really looking forward for your inputs ... i think I am close , something small is missing

Comment: possibly there may be one of TWO issues (1) either i am using incorrect URL to get JSON response (2) or I am not sure if REST APIs need a configuration

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to use `sonarqube.server.com:9000/api/metrics/domains`, I am able to get json response from this.

APIs that you can use are listed at:

`sonarqube.server.com:9000/web_api/api/metrics/domains/search`

but just remove "web_api" while calling, to get json response.